# Pop up should be visible in centre when i scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

My popup is not fixed in centre.. it scrolls down when i scroll down. I want it to be visible in centre even if i scroll down.. what is wrong with my code..

```
$(window).scroll(function() { $rootScope.initPosition("previousOrdersPopupId")});


// set the popup position depending on scroll position
$rootScope.initPosition = function(id){

        var thePopup = $('#' + id).parent();
        $rootScope.myPopupId = id;
        var popupPosition = $(window.parent.document).scrollTop();
        if (popupPosition < 100) {
            popupPosition = 100;
        }
        var deltaPosition = (popupPosition + thePopup.height()) - ($(window).height() -20);

        // in case of truncated popup resize the iframe
        if(deltaPosition > 0 && id != "loadingPopupId"){
            contentResize(popupPosition + thePopup.height() + 20);
        }
        // set the horizontal scrollBar
        var scrollLeftPos = ($(window).width() - thePopup.width()) / 2;
        $(window).scrollLeft(scrollLeftPos);
        thePopup.css('position','fixed');
        //thePopup.css('top',250+ "px");




        //center of the page
       //thePopup.css('top', ( $(window).height() - thePopup.height() ) / 2 +$(window).scrollTop() + "px");

        if(id=='transitionPopupId' && deltaPosition > 0){
            thePopup.css('top',deltaPosition - 20);
        } else {
          thePopup.css('top',( $(window).height() - thePopup.height() ) / 2 +$(window).scrollTop() + "px");

        }


};
```

Comment: use `position: fixed`

Comment: thePopup.css('position','fixed'); i have used fixed

Comment: you don't need js for this... at all. show us the markup and css